# JSON api output from MySQLi using PHP on LAMP server

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I'm building an application that has a MySQL db on an RDS instance, that I want to be able to serve data to the web/mobile app via an api. So I've built an Ubuntu lamp server EC2 instance for the web service.

In /var/www/html/ I've created my first php script;

```
<?php
class ArticlesAPI {
    private $db;

    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli("mysql-host.rds.amazonaws.com", "user", "password", "dbname");
        $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->db->close();
    }

    function top() {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT article_id, title, summary, article, image FROM top_articles;");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($article_id, $title, $summary, $article, $image);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo "$article_id";
            echo "$title";
            echo "$summary";
            echo "$article";
            echo "$image";
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
}

$api = new ArticlesAPI;
$api->top();

?>
```

This produces the required output, however it is just a blob of text. So I want to add a json_encode() to it. I've altered my function as follows;

```
    function top() {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT article_id, title, summary, article, image FROM top_articles;");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($article_id, $title, $summary, $article, $image);

            $this->rows = array();

            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    $rows['article_id'] = $article_id;
                    $rows['title'] = $title;
                    $rows['summary'] = $summary;
                    $rows['article'] = $article;
                    $rows['image'] = $image;
            }
            $stmt->close();
            echo json_encode($rows);
    }
```

It returns the last record within the query in the terminal and when I try to use it via a browser it appears to query the db however it doesn't return anything. I'm new to JSON, PHP and APIs in general. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$this->rows` and `$rows` are two totally different variables. as well, since you keep assigning to `$rows['...']` the way you are, you keep OVERWRITING previous rows' results, and you'll end up only with the LAST row of results being output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a much simpler way of creating the desired output;

```
<?php
class ArticleAPI {

        function top() {
                $db = new  mysqli("mysql-host.rds.amazonaws.com", "user", "password", "dbanme");
                $results = $db->query("SELECT article_id, title, summary FROM top_articles");

                $articles = array();
                while($article = $results->fetch_assoc()){
                        $article_id = $article['article_id'];
                        $articles[$article_id][] = $article['title'];
                        $articles[$article_id][] = $article['summary'];
                }
                $results->close();
                $db->close();
                $json = json_encode($articles);
                echo $json;

        }
}
$api = new ArticleAPI;
$api->top();
?>
```